# Play framework session via client cookie

Tags: session, cookies, playframework

In my application I want to keep a large amount of data in memory specific to a user currently accessing my web application in a user specific session. As for as I know play framework uses cookie to store session data which has a limit of 4k. How can I have much larger session data? Does ehacache memcache help here? This session has expiration time from last activity of the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a session data is cache'ble its better to keep it in Cache with key as userid and clear it when user logs off. Get it reloaded from DB on relevant DB update/delete. Keeping the content in external cache like memcache, will help you to scale well and will enable you to move to distributed cache in the long run, if required. Check this interesting article on [Share Nothing](http://zef.me/883/the-share-nothing-architecture).

Answer (score 2):

The idea with Play is to dispel the need for the session and the keeping of lots of information in memory. The problem with the in-memory approach, is that you tie the user to the specific server that their data is held, where-as the play share nothing approach means you can scale horizontally easily without worry of sticky sessions and the like.

The options you have are
 - store transient data in a temporary database that can be accessed via a userId or other unique idenifier of the users session. This database would be the equivalent of your server side session.
 - use a cache. However the idea of a cache is that if the information is not in the cache, it can be retrieved from the database (or other source) instead. A cache should not have to guarantee that the data will be available. If in the case of an in memory cache (like ehcache) if you have a load balanced set of servers, you may not be able to guarantee that all requets go back to the same server, so data in the cache may not be available on all servers for a particular session.

The answer to your question depends on your use case, but I think the database is your best approach based on the information you have supplied.

Comment: something went wrong with your first sentence, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Thanks. iPad auto correct change for to got, I must have tapped a wrong letter.